# How do I take input for the same graph from either a textbox or a dropdown?

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I want to build a simple dash app where the input is a stock symbol and the output is its stock price over some time period. However, I want to give the user 2 ways of choosing the input: either type it out in a textbox or select from a dropdown of some common stocks.

This is my code to do so:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children='Symbol to graph:'),
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='', type='text'),

    html.Div(children='Frequent options:'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
    options=[
        {'label': 'Apple (AAPL)', 'value': 'AAPL'},
        {'label': 'Microsoft (MSFT)', 'value': 'MSFT'},
        {'label': 'Amazon (AMZN)', 'value': 'AMZN'},
        {'label': 'Tesla (TSLA)', 'value': 'TSLA'}
    ],
    style={'width': '40%'},
    id='freq-inputs'
    ),

    html.Div(id='output-graph'),

    html.Div(id='freq-input-graph'),
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-graph', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
)
def update_value(input_data):
    start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    df = web.DataReader(input_data, 'iex', start, end)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

    return dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.close, 'type': 'line', 'name': input_data},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': input_data
            }
        }
    )

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-graph', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='freq-inputs', component_property='value')]
)
def update_value(input_data):
    start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 24) #datetime.datetime.now()
    df = web.DataReader(input_data, 'iex', start, end)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

    return dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.close, 'type': 'line', 'name': input_data},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': input_data
            }
        }
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

As you can see, I have had to write 2 divs for each kind of input (`html.Div(id='output-graph')` and `html.Div(id='freq-input-graph')`), and consequently 2 callback wrapper functions that are identical except for the input and output component IDs. That's because when I tried using the same output component div, I got an error saying:

```
You have already assigned a callback to the output
with ID "output-graph" and property "children". An output can only have
a single callback function. Try combining your inputs and
callback functions together into one function.
```

Apart from redundant code, there is another issue I face with this code. If I type out a stock symbol, it plots the graph; if I then select an option from the dropdown, the latter graph is plotted on the same div as the previous one, so we can see only one graph at any given time. However, if I first select an option from the dropdown, and then type out a symbol, it plots 2 different graphs.

This is because `html.Div(id='output-graph')` is declared/defined above `html.Div(id='freq-input-graph')` in the app layout definition. If I reverse the order, the opposite behaviour is noticed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `State` and not `Input` and then you will have only one function callback. this State could be assigned to a submit button and then when the user choose one Input between Dropdown or textbox and click on button the update will be done.